# Importing a document with the cell's background color

Tags: google-sheets

This might be a dumb question but is there a way to import a document sheet to another and get the color of the cell too? It's not colored using conditional formatting by the way, it's manually colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, unfortunately this is not possible to achieve in current Google Sheets.